# AppVeyor CI: use build script for linux and MSBuild for Windows

Tags: appveyor

### Scenario

I have a CMake project on AppVeyor that I am trying to add Linux Builds to. My Windows builds use a CMake generator in the `before_build` script to generate a visual studio solution which is built with `build: project`.

I want to perform my Linux builds with `build_script:` instead. However, when I add a build script to the matrix I get the error:

> The build phase is set to "MSBuild" mode (default), but no Visual Studio project or solution files were found in the root directory. If you are not building Visual Studio project switch build mode to "Script" and provide your custom build command.

### Attempted solutions

I have tried adding `build: off` and `build: Script` to the matrix however none of those options helped. Is my only option to define a script for Windows and use `build_script` on both platforms?

### Example

My `appveyor.yml` file looks like this

```
version: 'build-{build}-{branch}'

image:
  - Visual Studio 2017
  - Ubuntu

platform:
  - x64

configuration:
  - Release
  - Debug

environment:
  APPVEYOR_YML_DISABLE_PS_LINUX: true

install:
  - ps: .\install-dependency.ps1
  - sh: ./install-dependency.sh

for:
-
  matrix:
    only:
      - image: Ubuntu
  before_build:
    - mkdir -p build; cd build; cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=%CONFIGURATION% ..
  build_script:
    - make

 -
   matrix:
     only:
       - image: Visual Studio 2017
   before_build:
     - cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -A x64 .
   build:
     project: $(APPVEYOR_PROJECT_NAME).sln

test_script:
  - CTest -C %CONFIGURATION%
```

---

### Attempted solution details

For reference this is how I tried specifying the build options

```
matrix:
  only:
    - image: Ubuntu
build: Script
before_build:
  - mkdir -p build; cd build; cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=%CONFIGURATION% ..
```

---

### Further Research

I tried performing a standalone Linux build, everything works as expected and I don't need to modify any `script` parameters. Maybe AppVeyor does not support mixing build types even with a matrix set up.

```
version: 'build-{build}-{branch}'

image: Ubuntu

platform:
  - x64

configuration:
  - Release
  - Debug

install:
  - sh: ./install-dependency.sh

before_build:
  - mkdir -p build; cd build; cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=%CONFIGURATION% ..

build_script:
  - make

test_script:
  - ctest -C %CONFIGURATION%
```

Answer (score 1):

Although I have not found a solution to the question asked there is a workaround for building on both platforms. For Windows I can use the [default MSBuild](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-phase/) script `msbuild <project> /logger:"C:\Program Files\AppVeyor\BuildAgent\Appveyor.MSBuildLogger.dll"`.

```
version: 'build-{build}-{branch}'

image:
  - Visual Studio 2017
  - Ubuntu

platform:
  - x64

configuration:
  - Release
  - Debug

environment:
  APPVEYOR_YML_DISABLE_PS_LINUX: true

install:
  - ps: .\install-dependency.ps1
  - sh: ./install-dependency.sh

for:
-
  matrix:
    only:
      - image: Ubuntu
  before_build:
    - mkdir -p build; cd build; cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=%CONFIGURATION% ..
  build_script:
    - make

 -
   matrix:
     only:
       - image: Visual Studio 2017
   before_build:
     - cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017" -A x64 .
  build_script:
    - msbuild %APPVEYOR_PROJECT_NAME%.sln /logger:"C:\Program Files\AppVeyor\BuildAgent\Appveyor.MSBuildLogger.dll"

test_script:
  - ctest -C %CONFIGURATION%
```